# The behavior of the knitr button in RStudio when rendering an Rmd file sitting inside a blogdown static folder

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, render, blogdown

I have an Rmd file that I want to convert to a pdf file. Currently it is located in a subfolder of the "static" folder that is a part of my blog site structure created by the blogdown package. The problem is, when I hit the "Knit" button in RStudio, it calls `rmarkdown::render_site(...)` while I was expecting `rmarkdown::render(...)`. I do have a file `R/build.R` with a single line of a command `blogdown::build_dir("static")` so this is weird to me. When I tried to convert other Rmd files in a different folder (not associated with my blog folders/files) everything works perfectly fine as expected.

To get what I want, I am currently typing `rmarkdown::render("myfile.Rmd")` in the console, or I am using infinite moon reader, but neither is as convenient as the "Knit" button :(

The following is the output from `xfun::session_info('blogdown')` after updating the blogdown package to ver 1.1:

```
> xfun::session_info('blogdown')
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363), RStudio 1.4.1103

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
  LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 BH_1.75.0.0     blogdown_1.1    bookdown_0.21   digest_0.6.27   evaluate_0.14   glue_1.4.2     
  graphics_4.0.3  grDevices_4.0.3 highr_0.8       htmltools_0.5.0 httpuv_1.5.4    jsonlite_1.7.2  knitr_1.30     
  later_1.1.0.1   magrittr_2.0.1  markdown_1.1    methods_4.0.3   mime_0.9        promises_1.1.1  R6_2.5.0       
  Rcpp_1.0.5      rlang_0.4.9     rmarkdown_2.6   servr_0.21      stats_4.0.3     stringi_1.5.3   stringr_1.4.0  
  tinytex_0.29    tools_4.0.3     utils_4.0.3     xfun_0.20       yaml_2.2.1
```

edited:
I am not absolutely sure if this will help, but the `HW3.Rmd` file I want to convert to pdf goes like the following:

````
---
title: "Homework 3"
subtitle: "due Feb 2, 2021"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

When I save this file in the folder as in `C:/Users/jungl/Dropbox/GitHub/blog2020/static/Drexel_2021/HW3.Rmd` (here `C:/Users/jungl/Dropbox/GitHub/blog2020` is the root folder that holds all folders/files created by blogdown), the "Knit" button calls, unexpectedly, `rmarkdown::render_site(...)`. However, when I copy the same `HW3.Rmd` in a folder as in `C:/Users/jungl/Dropbox/test/HW3.Rmd`, "Knit" button works as expected and calls `rmarkdown::render(...)`. So it looks like the "Knit" button of RStudio somehow automatically determines whether it should call `rmarkdown::render_site(...)` or `rmarkdown::render(...)` based on whether the Rmd file under work is located in a (sub)folder of the root folder that holds blogdown-generated folders/files.

edited:
The Github repo is at `https://github.com/junglee0713/blog2020` and I just checked that the same problem still persists. The `HW3.Rmd` file that I want to convert to PDF is in `https://github.com/junglee0713/blog2020/tree/master/static/Drexel_2021`

Yet another edit: installing the dev version of **blogdown** seems to solve the problem (output below, note it still calls `rmarkdown::render_site(...)`), but with another issue. It renders other Rmd files in the same directory, say `HW1.Rmd` and `HW2.Rmd`, to respective PDF files.

```
==> rmarkdown::render_site('C:/Users/jungl/Dropbox/GitHub/blog2020/static/Drexel_2021/HW3.Rmd',  encoding = 'UTF-8');
  |..................                                                    |  25%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...................................                                   |  50%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE



processing file: HW3.Rmd
  |....................................................                  |  75%
  ordinary text without R code

  |......................................................................| 100%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ eval: symbol F


"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS HW3.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output HW3.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\jungl\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\jungl\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
output file: HW3.knit.md


Output created: HW3.pdf
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

So each time I render `HW3.Rmd` to a PDF, I get unsolicited updates of `HW1.pdf` and `HW2.pdf` too (as you see, I don't have any ggplot figure in `HW3.Rmd` and the output warns about picking better value with binwidth. `HW2.Rmd` does have `geom_histogram()` in it). What's more interesting to me is that in the folder where `HW1.Rmd`, `HW2.Rmd`, and `HW3.Rmd` are located, there are other Rmd files I convert to HTML (say `Drexel_2021_Lecture_1.Rmd`, `Drexel_2021_Lecture_2.Rmd`, and `Drexel_2021_Lecture_3.Rmd` -- they are xaringan slides) and they don't get affected by the knitting.

Comment: It'll be very helpful if you could provide the output of `xfun::session_info('blogdown')` in your post.

Comment: Thanks! I will post the outut from xfun::session_info('blogdown') below. However, I still have the same issue. The following is what I get after hitting the "Knit" button: ==> rmarkdown::render_site('C:/Users/jungl/Dropbox/GitHub/blog2020/static/Drexel_2021/HW3.Rmd',  encoding = 'UTF-8');
Rendering static/Drexel_2021/HW3.Rmd... Done.

Comment: In the future, please add the session info into your original post (you can edit it anytime), instead of posting it as an answer, since it's not an answer. I did it for you this time. Now I could you please provide a reproducible example? Because this is not reproducible in my own testing.

Comment: Thank you Yihui for editing my original post -- now I deleted the `xfun::session_info('blogdown')` from the answers following your suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome! If you provide a reproducible example, it will be much easier for me to help you.

Comment: I added an example(?) to the original post, not sure though if this could be regarded as _reproducible_.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the full website. A single Rmd file is not enough. You can make a copy of your current website project, delete other irrelevant files in the project, make sure the problem is still reproducible, and upload the project somewhere that I can download (e.g., make it a Github repo, or compress it to a zip file and share with Dropbox, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Yihui! The Github repo is at `https://github.com/junglee0713/blog2020` and I just checked that the same problem still persists. The `HW3.Rmd` file that I want to convert to PDF is in `https://github.com/junglee0713/blog2020/static/Drexel_2021`

Comment: By the way, the use of four backticks ```` is so cool!

Comment: More about the four backticks: https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/four-backticks-github/ I still can't reproduce your problem. When I click the Knit button, it generates the PDF correctly. Please see my updated answer and try the dev version of **blogdown**. If it still doesn't work, I guess we have to do a video chat with screen-sharing so I can possibly figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the very interesting post on the backticks!

Answer (score 2):

When you click the "Knit" button, **blogdown** does call `rmarkdown::render_site()` first, but this function [actually calls `rmarkdown::render()` eventually](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/8964242920ecfc10f5e31e0e22851153b5de23c7/R/utils.R#L118).

If it doesn't compile your Rmd file to PDF when you click the Knit button, please make sure you are using the latest version of **blogdown**, because it sounds like a bug that I have fixed a few months ago ([when in doubt, try to update packages](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/)).

If you install the current development version of **blogdown** (restart R after installation):

```r
install.packages('blogdown', repos = c(
  rstudio = 'https://rstudio.r-universe.dev',
  CRAN = 'https://cloud.r-project.org'
))
```

you will see detailed log of knitting in the R Markdown tab when you click the Knit button:

[image: The R Markdown tab]

Comment: I updated the blogdown package to version 1.1. Still the same issue though

Comment: Thank you so much! Installation of the dev version seems to solve the problem, but this time it renders some of other Rmd files in the same directory to PDF as well (maybe this was the case in the previous version of blogdown as well and I might not have noticed), as described in the newly edited part of the original post.

Comment: Great! I'm glad that we are making progress. It shouldn't render other Rmd files. It sounds like a problem of `R/build.R` or `blogdown::build_dir()`. I guess I know how to fix it, and I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @Jung-JinLee You can reinstall the dev version of blogdown (v1.1.7) and it should resolve the problem now.

Comment: Hi Yihui, **problem completely solved!!** Thank you so much for your time and effort so far, and for your great packages/books that benefit the whole R community!

Comment: Good to know! I'm glad that it finally worked. Thanks for the nice words!